# Bluetooth disconnects when SSH connection closes (RPi Zero 2)

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluez, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am trying to use a headless Rpi Zero 2 (Raspian 11) for bluetooth audio streaming.

I can establish a connection to a bluetooth speaker using `bluetoothctl connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` from an SSH connection and then stream audio through a pulseaudio A2DP sink using mopidy. This works!

What does **not** work is keeping the connection alive. As soon as i close the SSH shell, the bluetooth connection drops. I already tried to run bluetoothctl through `screen` without success.

If I connect again via SSH, I am not able to connect to my speaker and get
 `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed` from bluetoothctl.

syslog shows

```
bluetoothd[474]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
bluetoothd[474]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

when closing ssh and

```
 bluetoothd[474]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX: Protocol not available
```

when attempting to reconnect the speaker.

I'm quite new to Raspberries / Unix systems. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Can't comment because of low rep. This isn't a mopidy issue as far as I can see, as I can reproduce this behaviour without even starting mopidy. The speaker disconnects immediately after closing the SSH. I will edit in the output of `btmon` when I get home.

Comment: SSH and Bluetooth are unrelated. Might be related to modipy as it runs HTTP server. Type `sudo btmon`, do everything you do in order again and post the whole output.

Comment: `sudo btmon` did not really show anything useful here, was there anything specific to look for?
And yes, i tried buster. However, I use the pi for homeassistant. Busters old packages lead to conflicts everywhere, this is not really an option..

Answer (score 2):

If someone stumbles upon this: `pulseaudio` was the culprit. `pulseaudio` uses `systemd` to check if anyone is logged on, else it shuts down. This also closes the BT connection.

I fixed my problem by running `pulseaudio` as a system service (which is discouraged, maybe starting with `pulseaudio --daemonize` might also work) & adding mopidy and root to `pulse-access`. Seems fine so far!